# C#: Parse substring from a string by detecting whitespace

Tags: c#, regex, string

If I have various strings that have text followed by whitespace followed by text, how can I parse the substring beginning with the first character in the second block of text?

For example: 
If I have the string:
    "stringA stringB"

How can I extract the substring
    "stringB"

The strings are of various lengths but will all be of the format .

I'm sure this can be easily done with regex but I'm having trouble finding the proper syntax for c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
var test = "stringA stringB";
var elements = test.Split(new[]
{
    ' '
});
var desiredItem = elements.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

if you want to capture all whitespaces ([msdn tells us more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)):

```
var test = "stringA stringB";
//var elements = test.Split(); // pseudo overload
var elements = test.Split(null); // correct overload
var desiredItem = elements.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

**edit:**
why pseudo-overload?

- `.Split()` gets compiled to `.Split(new char[0])`
- not documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: This will only parse spaces, not all whitespace (tabs, newlines).

Comment: solution is based explecitely on oos example! ... did an update anyhow!

Comment: @Andreas: it's actually documented :) the keyword `params` means "any number of `char`s, possibly 0`. Empty list means 0 parameters. Cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

No RegEx needed, just split it.

```
var test = "stringA stringB";
var second = test.Split()[1];
```

and if you are in the wonderful LINQ-land

```
var second = "string1 string2".Split().ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

and with RegEx (for completeness)

```
var str2 = Regex.Match("str1 str2", @"\w (.*$)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: there does not exist such parameterless-method :)

Comment: due to compiler overload resolution!

Comment: You make it sound like that's a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

If all strings are separated by a whitespace you don't need a regex here. You could just use the Split() method:

```
string[] result = { };
string myStrings = "stringA stringB stringC";
result = myStrings.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need event the Split(). I think a simple IndexOf/Substring will do the job.

```
        var input = "A B";
        var result = string.Empty;
        var index = input.IndexOf(' ');
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            result = input.Substring(index + 1);
        }
```

Comment: -, as you need to know the length of the desired item, and this is not the wished behaviour of oo

Comment: I don't get you comment. What's the problem with my solution ? Even the author says : "How can I extract the substring ?" SUBSTRING ! He wants just "stringB". Why using Split() ? Why creating an array and using only the last item ? Why using LINQ for this simple case ?

Comment: Your solution might be faster and using less advanced techniques but it's definitely not easier to read. At least not for me. No downvote from me though.

Comment: Andreas misunderstanding on how it works might be a hint in some direction.

Comment: nope ... i know how it works, but ... what if `var input = "A B C";`? result would be "B C" ... so for correct splitting, we need to know the length of the desired item ... (re-read question: saying "various strings", "for example: 'stringA stringB'", ...)